# Finding Duplicate entries using 2 Tables

Tags: database, join, plsql

I have 2 tables i.e table1 and table2. Both tables have relational key mer_nbr. However, there are entries in table 2 which are duplicate and we need to find them out.

Sample data.
Table1

```
colA colB    colC    mer_nbr
1    01-Apr  03-Apr  1
2    02-Apr  03-Apr  2
3    03-Apr  04-Apr  3
4    04-Apr  05-Apr  4

Table2
colD colE    colF    mer_nbr delay
1    01-Apr  03-Apr  1       1
2    01-Apr  03-Apr  1       2
3    01-Apr  03-Apr  2       3
4    04-Apr  05-Apr  4       4
```

The result I need is mer_nbr 1 which has 2 entries in table2 with different delay but same period i.e. 01-Apr and 03-Apr.

I tried using `select table2.* from table1, table2 WHERE table2.colE = '01-APR-14' AND table2.colF = '03-APR-14'AND table1.mer_nbr = table2.mer_nbr;`

However, I am getting details for mer_nbr = 2 as well. I need to only get the result set with 2 rows shown for mer_nbr 1. i.e.

```
colD colE    colF    mer_nbr delay
1    01-Apr  03-Apr  1       1
2    01-Apr  03-Apr  1       2
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
with T as
(

select 1 as colD,to_date('01-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as colE,to_date('03-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as colF,1 as mem_nbr,1 as delay from dual
union
select 2 as colD,to_date('01-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as colE,to_date('03-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as colF,1 as mem_nbr,2 as delay from dual
union
select 3 as colD,to_date('01-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as colE,to_date('03-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as colF,2 as mem_nbr,3 as delay from dual
union
select 4 as colD,to_date('04-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as colE,to_date('05-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as colF,4 as mem_nbr,4 as delay from dual

)

select * from 
(
select colD,colE,colf,mem_nbr,delay,count(*) over(partition by cole,colf,mem_nbr) as cnt
from T
) where cnt>1
```